# pip3 install Adafruit package hangs on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi, adafruit

`pip3 install adafruit-python-shell` hangs, I've left it for a good 20 minutes. Works fine on Mac, but not on the pi.

```
pi@retropie:~ $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade adafruit-python-shell
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting adafruit-python-shell
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/adafruit-python-shell/adafruit_python_shell-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting clint (from adafruit-python-shell)
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/clint/clint-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Adafruit-PlatformDetect (from adafruit-python-shell)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/fa/6ee0fdaf63758c02e22bc834663fe4daf881f03dc5ec40ff613bc04a0c92/Adafruit-PlatformDetect-3.14.0.tar.gz
```

Same for `python3 -m pip install adafruit-python-shell`

Running with `--verbose` flag, it hangs on this:

```
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-unpack-b0e0ro32
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): files.pythonhosted.org:443
  https://files.pythonhosted.org:443 "GET /packages/44/fa/6ee0fdaf63758c02e22bc834663fe4daf881f03dc5ec40ff613bc04a0c92/Adafruit-PlatformDetect-3.14.0.tar.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 30874
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/fa/6ee0fdaf63758c02e22bc834663fe4daf881f03dc5ec40ff613bc04a0c92/Adafruit-PlatformDetect-3.14.0.tar.gz
  Downloading from URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/fa/6ee0fdaf63758c02e22bc834663fe4daf881f03dc5ec40ff613bc04a0c92/Adafruit-PlatformDetect-3.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=10a1d53347da76028c12c6d5bf73a4123bc44a0eb1c28aa6a94b53c70c2963ec (from https://pypi.org/simple/adafruit-platformdetect/) (requires-python:>=3.6.0)
  Added Adafruit-PlatformDetect from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/fa/6ee0fdaf63758c02e22bc834663fe4daf881f03dc5ec40ff613bc04a0c92/Adafruit-PlatformDetect-3.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=10a1d53347da76028c12c6d5bf73a4123bc44a0eb1c28aa6a94b53c70c2963ec (from adafruit-python-shell) to build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-pjs_dapw'
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-install-4z2h_rjo/Adafruit-PlatformDetect/setup.py) egg_info for package Adafruit-PlatformDetect
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, not sure what exactly this helped, but after running the command

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

I was able to install Adafruit PlatformDetect